# Game of/for a club

Tags: prepositions

I recently wrote a text containing the following sentence:

> "[...] So we keep asking while we await the next game of the national team of a country far away. "

The text was read by two English native speakers and one suggested to use FOR instead of OF:

> "[...] So we keep asking while we await the next game for the national team of a country far away."

Is that a correct way to express that we await the moment when the national team next plays (not when we next participate in the game of the national team).

Comment: 'We await the national team's next game.' // 'We await the next game played by the national team' would use the most appropriate preposition, but is much less idiomatic. The two original suggestions sound unnatural.

Comment: Ok, I've actually simplified the original sentence - unnecessarily perhaps. Please see the post edited.

Comment: Still both unnatural-sounding. Although there are probably examples where (a) 'of',  (b) 'for', would sound fine. Google "game of" and "game for" (and ignore obviously unrelated examples).

Comment: I googled **"next match*Liverpool is"** (everything in bold was my search term); I got a few results of "next match **against** Liverpool is", one for "next match **for** Liverpool is" and one for "next match **of** Liverpool is". So it's definitely not a common word order! Personally "for" sounds ok, whereas "of" sounds non-native (and the hit for that was from an Indian website).

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to preserve current word order it's going to be "for", not "of". But how about modifying it according to Edwin's first suggestion: "So we keep asking while we await the national team of a country far away's next game"? Personally, as a non-native speaker, I would not take such risk but perhaps it's perfectly correct?

Comment: Please don't be too insistent on preserving the current word order. It is more usual to say "a far away country's next game".

Comment: Thanks. "A far away country's next game" or " the national team of a country far away's next game"?

Comment: "So we keep asking while we await the next game of the national team of a far away country." It's made difficult by trying to put too many ideas into one sentence. In this context anyway, nobody would refer to a far away country, or their national game: those would already be known in a conversation, not vague descriptions. It reads like an unreal sentence from a bad phrase book.